# Why Solace performs LDAP bind every time before search and bind on behalf of client using LDAP Authentication?

Tags: solace

When I setup my VPN to use LDAP authentication, I noticed from my LDAP server log that Solace will perform bind operation before each search operation and bind operation on-behalf of client.  Below is my LAP server log:

(1) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='SolaceAdminDN@solace', type=simple)
```

(2) Search Request:

```
SearchRequestProtocolOp(baseDN='ou=clientOU,dc=kks', scope='BASE', derefPolicy='ALWAYS', sizeLimit=1, timeLimit=5, typesOnly=false, filter='(uid=clientID123)', attributes={memberOf})
```

(3) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='SolaceAdminDN@solace', type=simple)
```

(4) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='clientID123@clientOU.erp2.lta.gov.sg', type=simple)
```

(5) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='SolaceAdminDN@solace', type=simple)
```

(6) Search Request:

```
SearchRequestProtocolOp(baseDN='ou=clientOU,dc=kks', scope='BASE', derefPolicy='ALWAYS', sizeLimit=1, timeLimit=5, typesOnly=false, filter='(uid=clientID123)', attributes={memberOf})
```

(7) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='SolaceAdminDN@solace', type=simple)
```

(8) Bind Request:

```
BindRequestProtocolOp(version=3, bindDN='clientID123@clientOU.erp2.lta.gov.sg', type=simple)
```

Steps (1), (3), (5) and (6) are bind operations by Solace using the Admin DN as configured in LDAP Profile.

- clientID123 tries to login with a wrong password
- Solace Admi DN performs bind (step 1) before searching for
  clientID123 (step 2)
- Solace Admin DN performs bind (step 3) before performing bind for
  clientID123 (step 4)

My questions are:

1. Why does Solace perform bind every time before search and bind for
   client?
2. I believe steps (5) to (8) are retry by Solace before my client
   received Auth errror.  Is that true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Solace perform bind every time before search and bind for client?

The Solace router maintains a pool of LDAP connections to speed up future searches. What you are seeing in (1), (3), (5) and (7) are bind requests as the router fills up the connection pool.

Perform the packet capture after at least 10 more connection attempts, and there will be no more bind requests using the Admin Distinguished Name.

Note that this assumes that your LDAP server is not configured to deliberately close the LDAP connection after every search or bind attempt, resulting in the need to re-bind using the Admin DN for every lookup.

> I believe steps (5) to (8) are retry by Solace before my client received Auth errror. Is that true?

No. The Solace router rejects the client connection attempt immediately after being rejected by the LDAP server.

Your application is likely to be attempting to connect again, resulting in the Solace router to perform the LDAP lookup to authenticate the application again.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  FYI, I tested with 100 connections based on your suggestion and found that Solace only creates 20 bind requests using the Admin Distinguished Name and subsequently re-use those connections.